# can you shutdown a computer using javscript through nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a fun little beginner's project. I am trying to build a face recognition program using node js for my laptop to run upon login. I want it to take a picture whenever someone logs into my laptop and to check the face then I want it to shut down if it's not me. I will use the face-recognition npm package for the recognition part but I can't figure out how to shutdown my computer using javascript. I tried using the child_process package but it doesn't work when I type in exec('shutdown') for some reason. any ideas? (keep in mind I am a newbie so explain it to me like a 5-year-old).

Comment: Could you edit the question and post what code you have so far? And what operating system are you running this on?

Comment: What OS is this?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no native way for Node to shut down a computer. However, Node does have the ability to execute shell commands and these shell commands can be used to shut down a computer.

For example,

On Linux `shutdown -h now` will shut down the computer now.

Using [childprocess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) you can execute the shell command for shutdown.

See [here](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/child-processes/how-to-spawn-a-child-process/) for an example of how these work.